# Why does implicit casting from float to double return a nonsense number in my program?

Tags: c, casting, integer, double

I'm working on a Lab assignment for my introduction to C programming class and we're learning about casting.

As part of an exercise I had to write this program and explain the casting that happens in each exercise:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int a = 2, b = 3;
  float f = 2.5;
  double d = -1.2;
  int int_result;
  float real_result;

  // exercise 1
  int_result = a * f;
  printf("%d\n", int_result);

  // exercise 2
  real_result = a * f;
  printf("%f\n", real_result);

  // exercise 3
  real_result = (float) a * b;
  printf("%f\n", real_result);

  // exercise 4
  d = a + b / a * f;
  printf("%d\n", d);

  // exercise 5
  d = f * b / a + a;
  printf("%d\n", d);

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
5
5.000000
6.000000
1074921472
1075249152
```

For the last two outputs, the mathematical operations that are conducted result in float values. Since the variable they're being stored in is of the type double, the cast from float to double shouldn't affect the values, should it? But when I print out the value of `d`, I get garbage numbers as shown in the output.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: When you show code, you should generally tag what language the code is. I've added the `C` tag for you.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm new here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `"%d"` is for integers. Turn on warnings.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr No, `double` should use `%f`.

Comment: @melpomene Really ? are you sure ?

Comment: @melpomene ah crap. mixed up with `scanf`

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr No, you right it is **&lf**

Comment: @Michi actually `%lf` is not ok in C89. anyways, they both work in current standard.

Comment: Who care about c89 ? And yes, if we speak about c89.

Comment: @Michi yeah, anyways, long time no print. start to lose confidence now.

Comment: Anyhow, a halfway-decent compiler will generate a warning for such mismatches. The only severe fault here is that these warnings were either disabled or ignored!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What do you mean by warnings? I'm programming in a UNIX environment using emacs and compiling with gcc if that information helps any.

Comment: in C, a float value always has a trailing 'f'.   this line: `float f = 2.5;
` is actually defining a double then 'auto' converting it to float.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  Then the compiler can tell you about syntactic problems with the code.   The posted code raises two such warnings.  It is highly likely fixing those warnings will fix the problem your having with the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I print out the value of d, I get garbage numbers as shown in the output.

You are using `%d` as the format instead of `%f` or `%lf`. When the format specifier and the argument type don't match, you get undefined behavior.

`%d` takes an `int` (and prints it in decimal format).

`%f` takes a `double`.

`%lf` is either an error (C89) or equivalent to `%f` (since C99).